# How can I loop though pandas groupby and manipulate data?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to work out the time delta between values in a grouped pandas df.

My df looks like this:

```py
           Location         ID    Item      Qty      Time
0                 7  202545942  100130        1  07:19:46
1                 8  202545943  100130        1  07:20:08
2                11  202545950  100130        1  07:20:31
3                13  202545955  100130        1  07:21:08
4                15  202545958  100130        1  07:21:18
5                18  202545963  100130        3  07:21:53
6               217  202546320  100130        1  07:22:43
7               219  202546324  100130        1  07:22:54
8               229  202546351  100130        1  07:23:32
9               246  202546376  100130        1  07:24:09
10              273  202546438  100130        1  07:24:37
11              286  202546464  100130        1  07:24:59
12              296  202546490  100130        1  07:25:16
13              297  202546491  100130        1  07:25:24
14              310  202546516  100130        1  07:25:59
15              321  202546538  100130        1  07:26:17
16              329  202546549  100130        1  07:28:09
17              388  202546669  100130        1  07:29:02
18              420  202546717  100130        2  07:30:01
19              451  202546766  100130        1  07:30:19
20              456  202546773  100130        1  07:30:27
(...)
42688           458  202546777  999969        1  06:51:16
42689           509  202546884  999969        1  06:53:09
42690           567  202546977  999969        1  06:54:21
42691           656  202547104  999969        1  06:57:27
```

I have grouped this using the following method:

```py
ndf = df.groupby(['ID','Location','Time'])
```

If I add `.size()` to the end of the above and `print(ndf)` I get the following output:

```
(...)
ID      Location      Time
995812  696           07:10:36    1
        730           07:11:41    1
        761           07:12:30    1
        771           07:20:49    1
995820  381           06:55:07    1
        761           07:12:44    1
(...)
```

This is the as desired.

My challenge is that I need to work out the time delta between each time per Item and add this as a column in the dataframe grouping. It should give me the following:

```
ID      Location      Time      Delta
(...)
995812  696           07:10:36  0
        730           07:11:41  00:01:05
        761           07:12:30  00:00:49
        771           07:20:49  00:08:19
995820  381           06:55:07  0
        761           07:12:44  00:17:37
(...)
```

I am pulling my hair out trying to work out a method of doing this, so I'm turning to the greats.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `Time` column to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), sort by all 3 columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), get difference per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html), replace missing values to `0 timedelta` by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
#if strings astype should be omit
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].astype(str))

df = df.sort_values(['ID','Location','Time'])
```

---

```
df['Delta'] = df.groupby('ID')['Time'].diff().fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))
```

Also is possible convert timedeltas to seconds - add [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
df['Delta_sec'] = df.groupby('ID')['Time'].diff().dt.total_seconds().fillna(0)
```

Comment: Actually I'm thinking maybe OP does want to group by `Location` too, but there are no examples with size > 1 in the sample. So maybe sort_values by ID, Location, and keep first, and then groupby `ID`. Need to go now thats why I'm saying :)

Comment: @jezrael - Thanks for the response, this works perfectly for the most part. However, there is one caveat. In the desired outcome I posted above, there is a need to set `Delta` to `0` when the `ID` changes to a new `ID`. Would you use a Boolean mask to achieve this?

Comment: @nikugan - There is used `.fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))` for this reason, for you not working?

Answer (score 1):

If you just wanted to iterate over the groupby object, based on your original question title you can do it:

```
for (x, y) in df.groupby(['ID','Location','Time']):
    print("{0}, {1}".format(x, y))
    # your logic
```

However, this works for 10.000 rows, 100.000 rows, but not so good for 10^6 rows or more.

Comment: This is great insight into how to achieve the desired outcome using a groupby object. Thanks!